jsonschema2pojo использование своего исключения
коллеги
Столкнулся с проблемой, что в логи не 100% очевидно пишутся ошибки, если входящее сообщение не распарсилось на сгенерированный плагином jsonschema2pojo класс.
К примеру в случае с enum вижу, что по-умолчанию генерируется IllegalArgumentException в методе fromValue. Возможно ли его изменить?
Пример схемы
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "message",
  "properties": {
    "enum": {
      "type": "object",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/enum"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "enum": {
      "title": "Enum",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "status": {
          "enum": [
            "ACTIVE",
            "INACTIVE"
          ],
          "maxLength": 38
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Пример сгенерированного кода:

package ru.sbrf.llt.bonusoperationhistory.dto;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;


/**
 * Enum
 * <p>
 * 
 * 
 */
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "id",
    "status"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Enum {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Double id;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private Enum.Status status;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Double getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(Double id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public Enum.Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public void setStatus(Enum.Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(Enum.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
        sb.append("id");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.id == null)?"<null>":this.id));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("status");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.status == null)?"<null>":this.status));
        sb.append(',');
        if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
            sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
        } else {
            sb.append(']');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.id == null)? 0 :this.id.hashCode()));
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.status == null)? 0 :this.status.hashCode()));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((other instanceof Enum) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        Enum rhs = ((Enum) other);
        return (((this.id == rhs.id)||((this.id!= null)&&this.id.equals(rhs.id)))&&((this.status == rhs.status)||((this.status!= null)&&this.status.equals(rhs.status))));
    }

    @Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
    public enum Status {

        ACTIVE("ACTIVE"),
        INACTIVE("INACTIVE");
        private final String value;
        private final static Map<String, Enum.Status> CONSTANTS = new HashMap<String, Enum.Status>();

        static {
            for (Enum.Status c: values()) {
                CONSTANTS.put(c.value, c);
            }
        }

        Status(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.value;
        }

        @JsonValue
        public String value() {
            return this.value;
        }

        @JsonCreator
        public static Enum.Status fromValue(String value) {
            Enum.Status constant = CONSTANTS.get(value);
            if (constant == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);
            } else {
                return constant;
            }
        }

    }

}

Пример сообщения:
{
  "enum": {
    "id": 5,
    "status": "AC"
  }
}

Пример ошибки
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AC
at Enum.fromValue(Enum java:125) ~[classes/:na]

В примере понятно в какое поле попали не корректные данные, при этом если их будет больше 1 или 10. Ошибка в логах будет не информативна.
Рассматривал вариант отлавливать с помощью exceptionHandler, но так имя поля в котором проблема я не узнаю.
